# Mail setup returning error '10013'

Tags: python, sockets, email, flask

I'm trying to set up flask-mail for my program, however whenever i try to run the program and send an email a receive the error: ***[Errno 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permission.*** Does anyone know why this error is occuring?

My mail config is shown below.

```
MAIL_SERVER =  "smtp.gmail.com",
MAIL_PORT =  587,
MAIL_USE_TLS =  True,
MAIL_USE_SSL =  True,
MAIL_DEBUG =  app.debug,
MAIL_USERNAME =  "richardspythonprogramme@gmail.com",
MAIL_PASSWORD =  "Password1#",
MAIL_DEFAULT_SENDER =  None,
MAIL_MAX_EMAILS =  None,
MAIL_SUPPRESS_SEND =  app.testing,
MAIL_ASCII_ATTACHMENTS =  False,
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gmail has a setting that must be switched off in order for the application to be granted access to the mail server.

This setting can be found following this URL:     https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255